# Spring Data JPQL doesn't filter associated entity of OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I am working on spring data and using *Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE* and using JPQL to query the associated/embedded entity field for `@OneToMany` relation for the associated entity class filter but it retrieve all embedded object also used the `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` but not filtering associated object and loads all the object. Below are the entity and repo class.

First Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = AuthorityEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AuthorityEntity> authorities;

    //Setter getter
}
```

Second Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY")
public class AuthorityEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String authorityType;
    private String textType;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private UserEntity user;

    //Setter getter
}
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    UserEntity findByUsernameAndAuthoritiesAuthorityType(String username, String authority);
}
```

I also tried HQL `@Query("select u from UserEntity u JOIN FETCH AuthorityEntity a on u.id = a.user where u.username = ?1 and a.authorityType = ?2")` but it also fetching all child object not the filtering child.

Let me know where I am wrong, does any configuration required?

Comment: A where clause is not use to filter what is returned in the entities. It's used to select which entities should be returned. If I execute a query finding all users who have a w in their name, I'll get back a list of users, and you, Nawal, you will be part of this list, since you have a w in your name. Then, once I've found you, if I ask you "give me the letters in your name", you won't just say "w". You'll say "N, a, w, a, l". Same here.

Comment: If you want to select only specific AuthorityEntity instances, then you should query for AuthorityEntity instances, i.e. have them in the select clause of the query. That won't change the fact that if the user u has 3 authorities, then it has 3 authorities, and asking it for its authorities will, always, return its 3 authorities.

Comment: @JBNizet If it retrieve all the child then I have to filter the associated object and it make my code dirty.

According to the Spring Data JPA, a custom method **findByUsernameAndAuthoritiesAuthorityType(String username, String authority);** can be developed to do such query but it is not doing well and performing two queries at backed one for UserEntity and another to select all AuthorityEntity. Can I have any code sniped to perform filter on associated object.

Comment: I've told you what you need to do in my previous comments. Read them again.

Comment: If I understands correctly, I have to make another query to select the AuthorityEntity other than UserEntity, if it so then I am not using here the Spring Data JPQL feature and writing two query. The reason I want to perform only one query for the performance.

Comment: Not resolved yet

Answer (score 0):

After working hard I found a solution as JPA Entity Graph

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "USER.AUTHORITY", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("authorities") })
public class UserEntity
```

and

```
@EntityGraph(value = "USER.AUTHORITY", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
UserEntity findByUsernameAndAuthoritiesAuthorityType(String username, AuthorityType authority);
```

this worked perfectly for OneToMany and filter the child object as well but it also failing in case of ManyToMany relationship.